# Unity AAB build breaks with "split application binary" checked

Tags: unity, android, google-play

I am currently encountering a [challenge similar to the one described by a fellow Unity developer in this forum thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-work-with-obb.1054940//).

I am using Unity version 2022.3.10f and configuring asset bundles while building my project with the 'split application binary' option. However, upon uploading the resulting .aab file to the Google Play Console and attempting to play the game, I am experiencing a critical issue. It seems that the game is not retrieving essential assets, scripts, and texts from the obb file.

What's interesting is that when I build the project without the .aab format (creating an APK instead), the issue persists. Even though the obb file size is 1.2GB, the APK size is only 60MB.

I have applied a temporary fix by manually moving the obb file to the 'android/obb/(gamepackagename)' folder on the device for the non-AAB build (APK build), and the issue is resolved. However, this is not a sustainable solution.

I am seeking a permanent fix for this issue with AAB builds. Any insights or guidance on how to address this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This is a cross post from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77545737) where the question has been closed for not including enough details to reproduce or debug the problem. Reposting the same question without adding this information will lead to the same result.